Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file:
I already did AGP Upgrade Assistant, but still having this error, it's related to .pub-cache.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app_group_directory'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file: /Users/armagangok/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/app_group_directory-2.0.0/android/build.gradle. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Remove the attribute package="com.example.android" from manifest tag in AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.example.android">
      

The updated manifest tag should look like this
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
      
      

Add namespace 'com.example.android' in the module-level build.gradle file under the android block
android {
    namespace 'com.example.android' 
    // ... rest of your android block ...
}


If this not work in sender project then, i guess the problem is in this app_group_directory package that not included the namespace. See in the package pub dev latest publish was 3 years ago. So the sender can try implement this answer in the app_group_directory package build.gradle
